# screen flicker problem (OS independent)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, memory, display

I am facing an annoying screen flicker problem... I did so many tests, still cant find the actual cause of this. All the components are in warranty.. Please help me to find the problematic component!!

Here is the problem video link:
[screen flicker 2 on Vimeo](http://vimeo.com/22231224)
another one
http://vimeo.com/22231452

OS: Ubuntu 10.10 (64-bit)
RAM: 4GB DDR3
Phenom II X2 3.2 GHz black edition
mobo: ASUS - M4A785T-M

I had a 2GB DDR3 kingstone RAM.
Later I added a new 2GB DDR3 corsair RAM (2 months back)..

Before I thought that corsair is the culprit.. In fact the problem is very frequent when both the RAMs are attached...

It happens only when I do processor intensive jobs.. You can see in the video, then when the NetBeans parse the complete drupal installation, the flickering occurs.

But when I remove the corsair and keep only the kingstone, the flickering frequency is very less..

I have checked my Dell monitor by attaching with my Laptop, its perfectly okay..

I have tried all possible variations in the RAM slots, but the flickering doesn't stop Please check the video how it occurs.

Please tell me which component should I send to the service center?

Comment: If this is "OS independent", then doesn't that make it a **hardware problem**, and thus off-topic for Stack Overflow? Please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq); this site is for programming questions.

Comment: But my two cents? The one component you didn't mention in the question: the power supply. It's almost guaranteed to be weak, particularly considering that you say this happens when the processor is under a load. You've either overloaded the power supply, or it simply isn't putting out enough power, to drive all of your components when under a significant load. Buy a new, larger power supply. You may *also* need to buy a new graphics card, if you've damaged yours by starving it for power (but that's fairly unlikely). Start with the PSU, not the RAM. RAM doesn't cause video flicker.

Comment: Okay.. thanks for the reply. But can u please tell from where I can get these type of help? thanks

Comment: @Cody Gray Thanks a lot for showing me some direction.. And one more thing I forgot to explain is that recently I have added a new 500GB segate HDD.. The problem has increase drastically after that.. :( But my question is that, why it increases more when I add the corsair RAM? Is there any way for increasing the power from BIOS? I didn't built the desktop, the shopkeeper did, though at that time, one one HDD and RAM was there :(

Comment: Simple. Both hard drives and RAM draw power from your power supply (everything in your computer does!). If it was already straining to keep up with the load, drawing *even more* power from it is going to make the problem even worse. Hard drives are a much more significant power consumer than RAM, but the new stuff (especially the high-priced "designer" RAM like Mushkin and Corsair) is pretty power-hungry, too.

Comment: No, you can't increase the power from the BIOS. It's a hardware problem, not a software problem. The power supply unit puts out a fixed amount of power (measured in wattage). The more stuff you have running inside of your computer, drawing that power, the more power output your power supply unit needs to be able to produce. You'll need a larger one. If the screen was flickering when you bought it, take it back to the shop and show them the problem. Otherwise, you've overloaded it by buying extra components later (they gave you a low-quality one to save money), so you'll need to upgrade.

Comment: Hmmm.. Okay.. thanks Cody. Will upgrade my PSU :) BTW, did you saw the videos i showed in the actual post??

Comment: Nope. Steve Jobs and I are boycotting Flash.

Comment: @Cody Gray
Thanks a lot! Your diagnosis is correct! Yes it was having power problem.

Today I bought a new Corsair VX450w and the PC is running perfectly! without any flickering :) Now I have both the RAMs and HDDs.

Thanks Cody once again.. :)

Comment: @CodyGray, you may want to post your comments as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, the heat sink was not seated correctly.